# How in PhpStorm to show hints for all parameters of functions?

Tags: phpstorm

In  PhpStorm 2021.1.4 I have option to show parameters of functions, but

[image]

Why I see hint only on 3rd parameter in function with 3 parameters and only
2nd parameter in function with 2 parameters?
I show functions declarations commented ?

Also if there is an option to  show parameters of functions only for current line, not for all lines?

Comment: Those are "parameter name hints". They are shown when you use a RAW value (e.g. a number, a string, `true`/`false`) to better show what that is for. It is not shown when a variable/property is used (as you can figure what that parameter is for from the variable/property name). You can enable it for ALL parameters if you wish (not desired, too much noise) -- see the duplicate answer for that. 1) https://stackoverflow.com/a/41743975/783119 2) https://stackoverflow.com/a/69966400/783119

Comment: *"Also if there is an option to show parameters of functions only for current line, not for all lines?"* No. And that makes no much sense -- you move the caret and the text jumps (gets longer or shorter); esp annoying with long lines wrapping.  You can only have them ON or OFF for all, only show for raw values (default behaviour) and disable for specific function/parameter names.